# "Class constructor [] cannot be invoked without 'new'" instantiating own class in Vite project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

In a small Vue 3 project scaffolded with Vite, I've run into the `Class constructor XX cannot be invoked without 'new'` issue. My Googling suggests that the problem is a transpiled class extending a native class, but I have no such constructs in my code. I'm not fluent enough in Javascript/Typescript/transpilation/ESXXXX-whatever to figure it out.

Here's a minimum viable setup to demonstrate the problem:

1. `npm init vue@latest`
2. Add Typescript support, leave all other questions as default.
3. `cd vue-project; npm-install`
4. Replace contents of `App.vue` with the following:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Credentials } from './creds'

function logIn( creds: Credentials ) {
  // presumably log in here
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="logIn(new Credentials( 'aaa', 'bbb' ))">CLICK ME</button>
</template>
```

5. Add a new file, `creds.ts`, with the following contents:

```
export class Credentials {
  constructor(
    public readonly username: string,
    public readonly password: string
  ) {}
  toString = (): string => `${this.username}:${this.password}`;
}
```

6. `npm run build; npm run preview`
7. Open browser to `127.0.0.1:4173` and open browser's dev tools
8. Click the button, check the javascript console:
   `index.b42911a0.js:1 TypeError: Class constructor XX cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Two weird things:

1. No such error is seen in development (`npm run dev`), only when previewing the production build.
2. If you move the `Credentials` class into the script section of `App.vue`, the production build no longer throws the error.

What is it about instantiating a class from a different file, in an event handler, in production, that causes this mysterious error?

EDIT 2: I've removed the original question as it was all irrelevant.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No. I suspect it has something to do with the minification or obscuration done for release builds. But I've moved on; I was very new to Javascript/Typescript and Vue at the time, and I've since learned a lot about how things are 'expected' to be done. I use interfaces instead of classes, and I avoid putting code in event handlers, just a function name to call instead.

Comment: Ah right! I think the issue we had was calling new from inside a tag in our vue template area! We moved it to the script area and just called a method as you say, and this worked. It might be worth answering with that suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

(10/2023) I recently had this problem in Vue 3 with the composition API. I identified that in fact, if we use an assignment of an object instance or something similar within a tag, this will cause an error.

In development (debug) you will not be able to understand why this does not happen, but if you run your application in (preview) mode, this failure will happen.

The solution is that you must call a function and in that function you can do whatever you want.

In the code below, I made a CRUD filter and took the opportunity to expose it here for everyone. On the "clear" button where I call the "clear" method, everything works fine, but if I click on the "clear" button that assigns the variable directly in the event, this will generate an error in production.

```
<div class="row container-button">
    <span class="col-md-2">
      <button
        id="btn-filter"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        @click="emits('filter', item)"
      >
        Filter
      </button>
      
      <!-- this way works well -->
      <button id="btn-clear" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" @click="clear"> Clear </button>
      
      <!-- This form of use presents an error in production! -->
      <button id="btn-clear" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" @click="(() => filter = new QueryFilter())"> Clear </button>
    </span>
</div>

<script setup lang="ts">
let filter = ref<QueryFilter>(
  new QueryFilter()
);

const emits = defineEmits<{
  (event: "filter", value: any): QueryFilter;
}>();

function clear(){
  filter.value = new QueryFilter()
}
</script>
```